# Git prepend all commit messages in interactive rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I ran an interactive rebase up to commit `abcdef`.

```
git rebase -i abcdef
```

In the editor - Vim I changed all `pick hash` lines to

`reword hash PREFIX: Original commit message` using this vim command

`%s/pick \(\w\{7}\)/reword \1 PREFIX:/`

but then git goes on to prompt me to edit the message for every commit. Is there a simple way to batch this process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
GIT_EDITOR='sed -i "1s/^/PREFIX: /"' GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=vim \
        git rebase -i abcdef
```

or alternately you could

```
git -c core.editor='sed -i "1s/^/PREFIX: /"' \
        -c sequence.editor=vim \
        rebase -i abcdef
```

if you don't want to use the environment overrides.

If you know you're going to reword them all you could even sed the sequence, `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR='sed -i "s/^pick/reword/"'`.

Comment: @jtill What do you think about https://davidwalsh.name/update-git-commit-messages?

Comment: filter-branch works too, it's just a question of what's most convenient at the moment.  Sometimes you need a screwdriver, sometimes you need a crowbar, sometimes a dime would do, sometimes all of them would do the job eventually and it's just a question of what's handiest at the moment. `git commit --amend` for the checked-out commit, `git rebase -i` for hunk-shuffling and merge elision and light-duty rewords, `git filter-branch` for wholesale batch work where what you're doing isn't hunk-shuffling and the rebase overhead starts mattering.

Comment: The second example has a minor typo - missing slash in the sed command. It should be `sed -i "1s/^/PREFIX: /"` as above.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative answer using only `git`:

`git rebase -i --exec 'git commit --amend -m "PREFIX: $(git show -s --format=%s)"' origin/master`

You can also do this non-interactively (without the `-i` flag). Afterwards in the interactive window you can remove the exec directive after every commit where the prefix *shouldn't* be applied.

Explanation:

1. Using `rebase --exec` you can execute a command for every commit, this is quite generally useful.
2. Using `git commit --amend -m <MESSAGE>` you can change the message of the current commit.
3. Using `git show -s --format=%s` you can display the current commit message.

Putting it all together:

4. To prefix the message we must get the current message (3), and change the current message with amend (2), i.e. `git commit --amend -m "PREFIX: $(git show -s --format=%s)"`. The **double quotes** are important so that the command gets executed inside the message string.
5. To do this for every commit in the rebase (based on your `origin/master` branch here) you execute (4) on every commit, using **single quotes** otherwise every commit will get your last commit's message, and voilà you get the command above.