# Bulk rename commit messages on git interactive rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-interactive-rebase

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349905/git-prepend-all-commit-messages-in-interactive-rebase), I know it is possible to prefix/modify all commits from a git-interactive-rebase.

But is it possible to modify all to-be-renamed commits messages in a single action? For instance when you select the `reword` command to just take the modified message from that editor?

It is not only prefixing or replacing something.
It is arbitrary modifications that can only be manually done

Answer (score 2):

Rebase is *usually* a manual process, but there are some Unix-y ways of automating it:

Try setting `$EDITOR` to a `sed` command before running your `rebase --continue`. For example:

```bash
git rebase -i ...
```

Replace the first line's `pick` with `edit` or `e`, then the rest of the lines with `reword` or `r`.

Save-exit, then run:

```bash
export EDITOR="sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g'"
git rebase --continue
```

This'll replace all instances of `foo` in the commit message with `bar`.

Comment: AFIU the OP asks a slightly different question — how to make `git rebase` to use texts after `reword` in the TODO file as the commit messages.